# Undefined name 'Error' in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to connect sqlite db using Python3.

Code --

```
import sys,os
import datetime as dt
import sqlite3
from datetime import date,datetime

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return None


def main():
  database = r"C:\Users\prith\Documents\sqlitedb\filedb.db"
# create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting an error -- `there is an undefined name called 'Error'`

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, `Error` isn't defined. This seems simple enough. Why did you think it was defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems pretty clear, the name `Error` isn't defined.  I believe what you mean to use is `sqlite3.Error` instead.

Comment: No worries--it happens to the best of us. :-)